# How to quickly read in multiple excel files with multiple sheets in each - Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read in multiple excel files, each of which contain multiple tabs. My code works, however, it takes a long time to output the final dataframe. How can I optimize my code so that I am not waiting 30 minutes to get the final product?

I have tried to limit the sheets and files read into the loop in order to save time. I know that reading the file in as a csv saves time, however, converting the excel file to a csv makes it such that only the first tab is included. Perhaps there is a way to convert the sheets into csvs and read it in that way but I do not know how to do that.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np


invoicelist = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
invoicelist = pd.Series(invoicelist)
invoicelist1 = invoicelist[~invoicelist.str.contains('Analysis|Errors|M&T|MGMT|MT', case = False)]

invoice = pd.DataFrame()   


for f in invoicelist1:
    x = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    sheets = x.sheet_names
    sheets1 = pd.Series(sheets)
    sheets1 = sheets1[~sheets1.str.contains('Summary|sheet', case = False)]
    sheets2 = sheets1.tolist()
    for sheet in sheets2:
        newdf = x.parse(sheet)
        newdf['Sheet'] = sheet
        newdf['File'] = f
        invoice = invoice.append(newdf, ignore_index = True)
```

Like I said, the code works and outputs a dataframe with all the necessary data. However, it takes a long time to do so. What can I do to speed up this process?

Comment: Are the sheet names consistent across your multiple files? Or sheet numbers at least?

Comment: The excel files are very unorganized, partly the reason I am reading them into python. As an attempt to organize and analyze the data. The sheet names for some files are consistent but vary in other files.

Comment: I added two solutions, one for knowing the number of sheets before hand, and another brute force for guessing them. Since I can't actually time the two models, I can't guarantee faster performance than your nested loop.

Comment: Do the Excel files remain mostly the same? Could you save past information and only add new info somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `pd.concat` and using `pd.read_excel` directly, like this:

```
invoicelist = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
invoicelist = pd.Series(invoicelist)
invoicelist1 = invoicelist[~invoicelist.str.contains('Analysis|Errors|M&T|MGMT|MT', case = False)]
sheetnames = ['sheet_1', 'sheet_2', 'sheet_3', 'sheet_4']

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheetname)
               for file_path in invoicelist1
               for sheetname in sheetnames])
```

The caveat is that you should know before hand the index or name of the sheet_name. If so, I propose a brute-force approach:

```
df_list = []
for file_path in invoicelist1:
    i=0
    while True:
        try:
            df_list.append(pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=i))
            i+=1
        except IndexError:
            break

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

But again, brute force works, but doesn't perform well, which negates your endgoal.